# Complex system and Vagrant

Tags: apache, nginx, architecture, vagrant, virtualization

On production, we have a web infrastructure as it follows:

1. Load Balancer (haproxy)
2. API Server (PHP + apache)
3. Frontend Server (Javascript + nginx)
4. MySql Server
5. Redis Server

I'd love to start using Vagrant to make production environments exactly the same as the development ones, plus making it easy for a new developer to jumpstart doing his job.

The big question is: how should I build the box?
Should I put everything in one box or should I build more boxes? And how many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on convention you've reached with developers. Ask yourself one question: in what type of structure do you wish to work: distributed or centralized.

If answer is "distributed", you can make one box per one project. You won't mess up when you will nedd to up any project that got over last modification few time ago. But this method intakes much memory and storage space and sometimes it doesn`t make sense, if the most part of your projects based on the same production environment.

If answer is "centralized", it means one box per all projects builded on the same environment is enough for you. It saves plenty of time, but also it`s easy to confuse, when you're looking for an old project. You can set up Docker container per each project in your Vagrant box.

Additionally I'd like to suggest you [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro) usage for box building. That`s definitely clear instrument for this goal, it can make "ready to work" Vagrant box for every virtualization environment and execute shell scripts/CMS scripts. Just put in box everything essential for production environment, later developers can add some package dependencies through Vagrant provisioning and share it by Vagrantfile settings.